# find table row with most td and add equal # td to all other tablerows

Tags: jquery

I have a dynamic table created on my site

The table has multiple table rows with a different number of cells in each row so ofc it looks odd as the table doesn't look full with sytled

I can't access the dynamically create table to do any adjustments, so what can be done using jQuery to fix this

Example html

```
<table id="Table1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td> <! 3 td cells ->
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>  <! 5 td cells ->
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td> <! 2 td cells ->
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

What i want to do , is find which tablerow has the most td cells , then add blank td cells in all other table rows to equal the most shown , so html would look like this.

```
<table id="Table1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>  <! 5 td cells ->
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>  <! 5 td cells ->
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>  <! 5 td cells ->
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vanilla js approach which is simpler than using jQuery.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('#Table1'),
  rows = [...table.rows],
  maxCells = Math.max(...rows.map(r => r.cells.length));

rows.forEach(r => {
  while (r.cells.length < maxCells) {
    r.insertCell()
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}
```

```html
<table id="Table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: question , if the tr have "td" and "th" and i need to make both "td" and "th" same count , how would i go about that using your answer ?

Comment: Will the `<th>` always exist and will there only be one per row ( ie first cell)? If so, this solution should work as is

Comment: th will always exist , i used this , worked fine for "td" , but didn't add any "th"

Comment: Ohhh like for a heading row only? Using a `<thead>` and `<tbody>` would help for that case

Answer (score 1):

You would need to map the table rows to get the max columns, then map it again to append a blank td cell.

```
let maxCols = 0;
const rows = $("#Table1").find("tr");

rows
    .map((index, row) => {
        const cols = $(row).find("td");
        if (cols.length > maxCols) maxCols = cols.length;

        return row;
    })
    .map((index, row) => {
        const cols = $(row).find("td");

        if (cols.length < maxCols) {
            let currentCol = cols.length;

            while (currentCol < maxCols) {
                $(row).append("<td></td>");
                currentCol += 1;
            }
        }
    });
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/online-lorno/pen/bGeVedo

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code. At the moment I can only write this. You can modify the following code and optimize this for better performance

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var tr_arr = [];
        $('#Table1 tr').each(function(index, el) {
            tr_arr.push( $(this).find('td').length );
        });

        var max_td = Math.max.apply(Math,tr_arr);

        $('#Table1 tr').each(function(index, el) {
            var td_req = max_td  - tr_arr[index];
            var row = $(this);
            for (i = 0; i < td_req; i++) {
                row.append('<td></td>');
            }

        });
    });
```